# SharePoint list updation using powershell script from sql trigger

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sql

I need to update a SharePoint list whenever a datachange happens in the sql cuastom table. I am trying achieve this by writting a trigger in the sqltable and calling PowerShell script to update list in the trigger.

Can anyone tell me the syntax to call the PowerShell script in the trigger?

i was using tthe command below for executing the PowerShell script in sql

xp_cmdshell 'c:\change.ps1 -Application_Number 100'

It gives me an error c:\change.ps1 is not recognized as an internal  or external command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a small Stored Procedure and create a Trigger within, to execute the PowerShell (1.0 or 2.0) script using `xp_cmdshell`. Here is a [small example](http://sev17.com/2010/11/executing-powershell-in-sql-server-redux/) on how to do it

P.S. But I sincerely hope that you **won't** manipulate directly with SharePoint related configuration or content databases since it is not supported by Microsoft.